# How do I migrate VS 2010 to VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am currently using Visual Studio 2010, I would like to migrate to Visual Studio 2015.

Should I migrate 2013 first then migrate to Visual studio 2015? Or directly migrate to VS 2015?

Comment: Opening the solution in VS2015 and letting the normal upgrade preocedure work should do the trick. No need to upgrade first to 2013.

Comment: In My Solution I have below projects  1. web Form 2. MVC  3.Console 4.web services 5.WCF 6. Window services ... U mean to say everything will be upgraded automatically with FW 4.6 ?

Comment: It should work. After the upgrade, you can manually check in the project properties of your project what framework version is set.

Comment: If you have Windows8+, double click on the ISO file and Windows should mount it. Otherwise you have to use a tool to mount it, like DaemonTools.

Comment: When I opened Vs2010 project in VS2015, I was not asked anything to upgrade the FW 4.6. It opened succefully with old FW 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this worked:

[image: Reload Project menu item in the Solution Explorer]

1. Right click on the project.
2. Click OK.
3. Depending on the project type you might get suggestions or the migration might just happen.

That's it.